# KendoUI grid not showing up with the data on the screen

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Hi I am developing an angular 2 application with Kendo UI controls. I am following the example of the kendo UI site to set up the Kendo Grid. For some reason there are no errors an nothing showing up on the screen. The data is stored in the local products.js file which is referred in the application and  bound to the datasource. Please see the code below

**Product.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>



    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link href="../../assets/css/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../../assets/css/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../../assets/css/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../../scripts/kendo/2016.3.1028/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../scripts/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="../../scripts/shared/products.js"></script>
        <div id="example">





            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: products,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" }

                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        scrollable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                            { field: "ProductName", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },

                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

**Products.js**

```
var products = [{
    ProductID : 1,
    ProductName : "Chai",
    SupplierID : 1,
    CategoryID : 1,
    QuantityPerUnit : "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    UnitPrice : 18.0000,
    UnitsInStock : 39,
    UnitsOnOrder : 0,
    ReorderLevel : 10,
    Discontinued : false,
    Category : {
        CategoryID : 1,
        CategoryName : "Beverages",
        Description : "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    }
}, {
    ProductID : 2,
    ProductName : "Chang",
    SupplierID : 1,
    CategoryID : 1,
    QuantityPerUnit : "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    UnitPrice : 19.0000,
    UnitsInStock : 17,
    UnitsOnOrder : 40,
    ReorderLevel : 25,
    Discontinued : false,
    Category : {
        CategoryID : 1,
        CategoryName : "Beverages",
        Description : "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    }
}];
```

I have verified all the references to the javascript and css files and they seem right. I have tried to check if there are any errors in the console window using developer tools.

Comment: you need to create a datasource before using it in the same file such as http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-display-json-data-source-in-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: Tom, there is anything wrong with this. I've tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I  have added the following before assigning the datasource                   var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: products
            });   But this dosent seem to work

Comment: Tom - I just tried your above code with references to the cdn versions of the CSS and JS resources and it renders the table correctly. My guess is the one or more of your resources are not getting loaded - double check the paths to all of the scripts and styles, also check the network tab in devtools

Comment: How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: @Tom can you please check if there is any error in the inspect element? My only concern is regard this path on script tag:  <script src="../../scripts/shared/products.js"></script>

Comment: Hi, I did check the path and it was correct. I am able to print the JSON object returned by service in div element. I also tried assigning the data directly in the grid but that didnt work. I have a feeling the jquery isnt working as I tried the document.write withing the document.ready function but it dint seem to print anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code.

Could you please provide us with info about what browser are you using and what is the file structure of your project? You are using some complicated paths to your js and css files.

Anyway I've setup 2 working examples for you.

1. Codepen: http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/XNNKEv
2. github project [github link](https://github.com/xszaboj/kendo-test)

I doesn't answer your question why you don't see any errors on the page. But I hope it will help.

Code is same as yours:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: products,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" }

                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "ProductName", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },

        ]
    });
});
```

Here is my Firefox network capture. Could you please include yours for my github project so we could compare?
[image: firefox network]

Comment: Even I fail to understand how it is working for you and not me. I am able to print the JSON object returned by service in div element. I also tried assigning the data directly in the grid but that didnt work. I have a feeling the jquery isnt working as I tried the document.write withing the document.ready function but it dint seem to print anything.

Comment: I did install firefox and firebug but cant be able to trace the issue. Its certainly got to do with jquery not working. I tried to amend the link by adding the type attribute as well <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: could you please include firefox network as I did so we could compare?